# USB Audio Problem

Tags: sound, usb, power-management, arm

I have a Corewind WiFiG25 board based on the AT91SAMG25 400 MHz following
Arm processor running Linux 3.6.9 built using Buildroot. I am attempting to play mp3 files using mpg123 connected to an ALSA device consisting of a USB connected TI PCM2900C CODEC. The files play, but they "crackle" during playback.

I suspected the processor of being overloaded playing the files, but the top command reveals less than 20% CPU utilization. To further test this hypothesis I made the CPU very busy to see if the issue got worse. I made the CPU busy using the following command

```
cat /dev/zero /dev/null
```

This consumed 95% or more of the CPU. The issue did not get worse, but instead the audio noise vanished completely and the audio was great. I now suspect power management issues are involved.

I configured the kernel without power management, but that resulted in the following during boot:

```
usb 2-3: new full-speed USB device number 2 using at91_ohci
usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=08bb, idProduct=29c0
usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 2-3: Product: USB AUDIO  CODEC
usb 2-3: Manufacturer: BurrBrown from Texas Instruments
8192cu: Unknown symbol device_init_wakeup (err 0)
insmod: can't insert '/lib/modules/3.6.9+/8192cu.ko': unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter
```

The rtl8192cu wifi module can't load, disabling wifi.

I have searched extensively for other ideas or approaches in an effort to validate my latest thinking, but to no avail. Lots of discussion on how to enable power-management and audio issues on linux desktop systems, but not this sort of embedded environment.

Any thoughts, hypotheses, test, etc. you might think of would be welcome. I would rather not leave the `cat /dev/zero > /dev/null` in my final system :)

Comment: Are there reasons you believe CPU usage and/or power management may be to blame? AFAIK that is not how any of this works.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: @cremefraiche I simply guessed at CPU usage which led to the experiment to simply load the CPU more and see if things got worse. Things didn't get worse they got much better / perfect. The outcome led me to believe that if the CPU was busy and couldn't sleep things worked well. All conjecture, hence my request for help and suggestions.

Comment: @Elder Geek in my implementation lsb_release is not available in BusyBox or otherwise.

Comment: I'm sorry, askubuntu is restricted to questions regarding Ubuntu and it's variants. You may wish to post your question on our sister site.   Unix & Linux at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so buildroot is off-topic here as well. However, on http://unix.stackexchange.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  ;-)